# Why does `-threaded` make it slower?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc

A simple plan:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS

main = do
  wc <- length . BS.words <$> BS.getContents
  print wc
```

Build for speed:

```
ghc -fllvm -O2 -threaded -rtsopts Words.hs
```

More CPUs means more slowly?

```
$ time ./Words +RTS -qa -N1 < big.txt
331041862

real  0m25.963s
user  0m21.747s
sys 0m1.528s
$ time ./Words +RTS -qa -N2 < big.txt
331041862

real  0m36.410s
user  0m34.910s
sys 0m6.892s
$ time ./Words +RTS -qa -N4 < big.txt
331041862

real  0m42.150s
user  0m55.393s
sys 0m16.227s
```

For good measure:

```
$time wc -w big.txt
 331041862 big.txt

real    0m8.277s
user    0m7.553s
sys 0m0.529s
```

Clearly, this is a single-threaded activity. Still, I wonder why it slows down so much.

Also, do you have any tips, how I can make it competitive with wc?

Comment: well *-threaded*  adds overhead (and as you said you don't need it with this) - to get faster I would probably try non-lazy-IO or pipe/conduit (how big is big.txt?)

Comment: Thank you @Carsten. I will try pipes. `big.txt` is for benchmarking and could be unlimited. It might help if ByteString used bigger chunks (or smaller, who knows?). Better would be to avoid allocation and use a fixed buffer like C if it were possible. I would like to put some further processing in other threads (such as counting characters and lines) but with such overhead there is no advantage in doing so.

Comment: The bottleneck is clearly IO and perhaps memory here; the CPU doesn't do anything interesting at all. The garbage collector may well be the culprit, I believe multithreaded GC is substentially more complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's GC. Executed your program with `+RTS -s` and the results told everything.

-N1

```
D:\>a +RTS -qa -N1 -s < lorem.txt
15470835
   4,558,095,152 bytes allocated in the heap
       1,746,720 bytes copied during GC
          77,936 bytes maximum residency (118 sample(s))
         131,856 bytes maximum slop
               2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      8519 colls,     0 par    0.016s   0.021s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1       118 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.004s     0.0000s    0.0001s

  TASKS: 3 (1 bound, 2 peak workers (2 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.842s  (  0.855s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.016s  (  0.025s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.016s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.874s  (  0.881s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    5,410,809,512 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.2% of total user, 97.4% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

-N4

```
D:\>a +RTS -qa -N4 -s < lorem.txt
15470835
   4,558,093,352 bytes allocated in the heap
       1,720,232 bytes copied during GC
          77,936 bytes maximum residency (113 sample(s))
         160,432 bytes maximum slop
               4 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      8524 colls,  8524 par    4.742s   1.678s     0.0002s    0.0499s
  Gen  1       113 colls,   112 par    0.031s   0.027s     0.0002s    0.0099s

  Parallel GC work balance: 1.40% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 6 (1 bound, 5 peak workers (5 total), using -N4)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.950s  (  1.415s elapsed)
  GC      time    4.774s  (  1.705s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    6.724s  (  3.121s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,337,468,786 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  29.0% of total user, 62.5% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 21082
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

The most significant parts are

```
                                   Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      8524 colls,  8524 par    4.742s   1.678s     0.0002s    0.0499s
```

and

```
Parallel GC work balance: 1.40% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)
```

When `-threaded` switch is on, at runtime ghc will try its best to balance any work among threads as far as possible. Your whole program is a sequential process so the only work can be moved to other threads are GC, while your program in fact cannot be GCed in parallel so these threads wait for one another to complete their job, resulting a lot of time wasted on synchronization.

If you tell the runtime not to balance among threads by `+RTS -qm` then sometimes -N4 is as fast as -N1.